# What type of stresses occur during bending of steel rod?

Tags: continuum-mechanics, stress-strain

When an external weight (and/or sometime by weight of its own) is tied to a horizontal metal rod, whose ends are supported by two opposite walls, the rod sags, bends due to the weight.
[image: Figure]
My question is what types of stresses occur during its bending?
My thought is that both shearing and tensile stresses occur during its bending.
Also how can we quantitatively express them, given that we know Young's modulus, initial length, area of cross section, weight of object, and also how do we measure the amount of deviation δ by which it bended?

Comment: A rough approximation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Bernoulli_beam_theoryA better approximation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timoshenko_beam_theory.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because This is standard (and elementary) theory, and the OP has shown no effort to research the answer.

Comment: The simplest description is that the part of the beam on the outside of the bend is under tensile stress axially, and the part of the beam on the inside of the bend is under compressive stress axially.  More accurately, the axial tensile stress varies linearly with distance through the thickness of the beam, with zero tensile stress at the centerline.

Comment: @Adi One problem are equations to be used, another is exact
specification of the problem. To me your question appears defective on the latter side. You wrote the rod is supported by walls, then
presented a drawing. I find the drawing inconsistent with the words.
Usually when a rod is constrained by a wall, it means that it is *stuck* into the wall, so that at the ends the rod must remain horizontal. If you draw it slanted, that means it's simply *supported*, but then a wall isn't the right thing to do so.

Comment: @Adi Clearly the former condition (stuck) is harder than the latter, since it not only fixes the positions of rod's ends, but also the rod's direction there. Intuitively in the second case $\delta$ would be much smaller.

Answer (score 3):

A beam under bending has all six independent components of the sreees tensor different from zero. However, some of them are small, thus allowing the formulation of the so-called beam theories, which condense the degrees of freedom of the problem.

The Bernoulli-Euler beam theory is the most used one; it assumes that the cross section is rigid in it own plane and out of plane. It also assumed that shear strains are small; therefore, the cross section remains perpendicular to the neutral axis after the deformation.

The Bernoulli-Euler beam theory gives good results for the normal strees (which are the most important for slender beams). This stress is normal to the cross section and is calculated as:

$$\sigma =\frac {M y}{I}$$

The shear stress can be calculated analytically for some simple cross sections. However, the general problem requieres numerical treatment because the differential equation of elastic equilibrium can not be solved analytically. The finite element method is typically used for that purpose.

For additional details see [Bernoulli-Euler beam theory](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Bernoulli_beam_theory.)

Comment: Thanks!! Actually I am a high school student, so my physics textbook have mentioned only about longitudinal, shear and volumetric stresses. Also without use of tensors but with use of elementary calculus, so it would do more help if you can explain the equation My/I, thanks

Comment: M is the bending moment, y is the location of the point where you want to calculate the stress and I is the inertia moment of the cross section.